# Upgrade apps with apt to beta

Tags: apt, upgrade, beta

I would like to do this. I know how to do this with snap:

```
sudo snap install <app> --beta
```

But I would like to know how to do this with apt.

Comment: apt does not work this way.  Usually you need to find a alternative ppa.

Comment: So, I could not upgrade the software center with apt?

Comment: No, official apt softwares are feature-freezed until next releases.

Comment: I agree with Alvin, however, you can run `apt-cache madison <app>` and it will show you all the versions of the application that is available through the PPAs that are configured for you that you can install.